# s2i haskell stack failed to build cardano-sl

Tags: stack, haskell-stack, cardano

Im trying to build my cardano full node application

I am having some issue with the stack.yaml, I am using current stack-2.1.1 and I installed all the dependencies for cardano-sl:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-sl/blob/develop/docs/how-to/build-cardano-sl-and-daedalus-from-source-code.md

```
---> Building application from source...
Going to build:  cardano-sl-networking cardano-sl-binary cardano-sl-util cardano-sl-crypto cardano-sl-core cardano-sl-db cardano-sl-chain cardano-sl-infra cardano-sl cardano-sl-node cardano-sl-client cardano-sl-generator cardano-sl-auxx cardano-sl-tools cardano-sl-explorer cardano-sl-wallet
Building cardano-sl-networking

stack build --ghc-options=" -Wwarn" --test --no-haddock-deps --bench --jobs=1 --no-run-tests --no-run-benchmarks --dependencies-only  cardano-sl-networking

Could not parse '/opt/app-root/src/stack.yaml':
Aeson exception:
Error in $.packages[32]: failed to parse field 'packages': expected Text, encountered Object
See http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/
Build failed
ERROR: An error occurred: non-zero (13) exit code from mycardano-s2i
```

My stack.yaml:

```
resolver: lts-12.17

flags:
ether:
disable-tup-instances: true

extra-package-dbs: []

packages:

    util
    util/test
    networking
    binary
    binary/test
    crypto
    crypto/test
    core
    core/test
    db
    db/test
    infra
    infra/test
    chain
    chain/test
    lib
    generator
    client
    auxx
    script-runner
    explorer
    node
    tools
    tools/post-mortem
    utxo
    wallet
    node-ipc
    faucet
    acid-state-exts
    x509
    cluster
    mnemonic
```

I have read some workaround where you have to update stack, but I am the moment I am using the last release 2.1.1.